# Unable to compile sass using gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I am new to js, and I'm following a tutorial. I installed gulp and ran into an error when trying to compile sass files. error is below:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\*****\Documents\GitHub\*****\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
at Gulp.task (C:\Users\*****\\Documents\GitHub\*****\\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\*****\\Documents\GitHub\*****\\gulpfile.js:38:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

I tried to follow the syntax in the gulp documentation, but I am unable to get it to work.

My code:

```
'use strict';

//dependencies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var once = require('async-once');


///////////////
// - SCSS/CSS
///////////////

var SCSS_SRC = './src/assets/scss/**/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/assets/css';

// Compile SCSS
gulp.task('styles', function () {
gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST))
});


// detect changes in SCSS
gulp.task('watch_scss', function() {
gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, ['compile_scss']);
});


// Run tasks
gulp.task('default', ['compile_scss']);
```

Comment: You are using gulp3 syntax, look at gulp4 documentation.  So change `gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, ['compile_scss']);` to `gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, gulp.series('compile_scss));`  and same for your `default` task.

Comment: Thank you. Will check the gulp4 docs.

Comment: After checking the gulp docs, I figured out that there is not much changes between gulp 3 and gulp 4. Using gulp.watch and gulp.series, i fixed the error. Thanks again for you assistance Mark. Sorry it took long to respond.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have a return from you gulp task.

Try:
// Compile SCSS

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
**return** gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST))
});
```

Comment: No `return` does not result in the error: `Task function must be specified`.  The answer is in my comment as the OP saw.